# How can I update the text content using `addEventListener`?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I’m making kind of a funny website where it gives you a scrambled word and you have to unscramble it. To add to the vibe of the page, I want to scramble the title every time you type a letter, just for the fun of it. Unfortunately, when using `addEventListener`, it seems to run the code then add the letter when I type in the box. You will see this if you type one letter or backspace one letter. If you have any other amount of letters though, it will be find. Is there a better way to see if I'm typing in the box to update the title?

```js
var points = 0

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function win() {
  points += 1
  document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = "Points:" + points
  currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = scramble(currentWord)
  guess = ""

  currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = scramble(currentWord)
}
guess = ""
words = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange", "pear", "grape", "peach", "mango", "strawberry", "blueberry", "blackberry", "raspberry", "watermelon", "cantaloupe", "pineapple", "kiwi", "avocado", "coconut", "papaya", "plum", "apricot", "lemon", "lime", "fig", "nectarine"]

function scramble(a) {
  a = a.split("");
  for (var b = a.length - 1; 0 < b; b--) {
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * (b + 1));
    d = a[b];
    a[b] = a[c];
    a[c] = d
  }
  return a.join("")
}

var textBox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
var value = textBox.value;


textBox.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  console.log(currentWord)
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log(textBox.value)
    guess = textBox.value
    textBox.value = ""
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Unscramble the Word"
    if (guess === currentWord) {
      console.log("YOU WINNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN")
      win()
    }
    return;
  }

  if (textBox.value === "") {
    console.log("not working")
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Unscramble the Word"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = scramble("Unscramble the Word")
  }

});
currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = scramble(currentWord)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}

#center {
  text-align: center;
}

#word {}

#myTextBox {}

#title {}

#party {}

#points {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Random</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <div id="center">
    <h1 id="title">Unscramble the Word</h1>
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p id="word">SOMTHING IS VERRY VERRY WRONG</p>
  </div>
  <div style="height:100px; text-align:center" id="party"></div>
  style="text-align: center;"><input type="text" id="myTextBox" autocomplete="off"></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;" "<p id="points " >Points:</p>
  <script src="script.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried keyup?

Comment: Next time it would be great if you actually made a minimal example of the issue, now there is a lot of code to search through when parsing your question and a fair bit of the code doesn't do anything (Empty CSS, unused sleep function...) and/or is actually invalid. Even after the edit I'm afraid.

Comment: @JoelPeltonen the css isnt empty, i use if for findelmentbyid, but i will clean up my code next time

Comment: @ImBadAtMath Oh I think I was a little unclear in my comment, I actually meant empty CSS rules like `#word {}` :) Hope the answer helped you out a little in any case!

Answer (score 1):

I think for you the `input` event would work the best; See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Demo:

```js
const words = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "orange"]
let currentWord;

function scramble(a) {
  return a.split("").sort(x=>0.5-Math.random()).join("")
}

function reset() {
  currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = scramble(currentWord)
}

function win() {
  alert("You win, it was "+currentWord+"! Try a new one!")
  reset()
}

document.getElementById('guess').addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === currentWord) {
      e.target.value = ""
      win()
    }
})

reset()
```

```html
<p>Your word is <b id="word"></b></p>
<input type="text" id="guess" autocomplete="off">
```